# Powershell script that deletes files that start with "pict", end with ".dat" and are older than 2 years not working

Tags: powershell, match

I am currently trying to write a script that deletes all files in a folder which are older than 2 years old and have a name like "pictxxxx.dat". It should search for the "pict" at the beginning, and ".dat" at the end.
This is my code:

```
    Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" | ForEach {
  $lastWrite = $_.LastWriteTime
  $timespan = new-timespan -days 730 
  if (((get-date) - $lastWrite) -gt $timespan) {
    if ($_.Name -Match "pict\d+(\.dat)^") {
      Remove-Item $_ -WhatIf
    }
  }
}
```

It's just not doing anything tho. The command line stays completely empty whenever i run it. Removing the WhatIf also doesnt help.

Any and all input would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a tip, add a temporary `Write-Verbose $_.Name -Verbose` the line after your first `If` and the run your script...  That way you'll see if it at least enter the first condition or not, then you can align your efforts in the good direction. 

If it enter the first `If`, then at least you'll know that the problem lies with your second `If` statement. If it doesn't even go through the first `If`, that is that part you need to look at first...

Comment: @vonPryz It is now successfully recognizing the files that should get deleted, but the path is incorrect? They are all located in c:/Temp, but the output when i run the script is 

"Cannot find path C:\Windows\System32>WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\*filename* because it does not exist."

Comment: Isn't this the code with that I helped you in your previous question? You would seek help there in the comments. Why did you asked a new question?

Comment: @WasifHasan Because the original question got locked. But yes, this is what you  helped me with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## "pict\d+(.dat)^" should be "^pict\d+(.dat)"

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp"
$comparetime = (get-date).AddDays(-730)
$matchstring = "^pict\d+(\.dat)"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $lastWrite = $file.LastWriteTime
    $name = $file.name
    $fullname = $file.fullname
    if ($lastWrite -lt $comparetime -and $name -match $matchstring) {
        del $fullname
        Write-Host "del $fullname" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```